# SeriesGroupBy vs DataFrameGroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new to programming, python and pandas.
I'm trying to undeestand why this code gives me proper result:

Original DF:

[image: Original DF]

```
df_cat = df_cat.groupby(['cardio','variable'])['value'].value_counts().to_frame().rename(columns={'value': 'total'}).reset_index()
```

And this one returns error:

```
df_cat = df_cat.groupby(['cardio','variable'], as_index=False)['value'].value_counts().to_frame().rename(columns={'value': 'total'}).reset_index()
```

**AttributeError: '`DataFrameGroupBy`' object has no attribute '`value_counts`'**

I understand that the only difference is "`as_index=True/False`". In the first case I get `SeriesGroupBy` and able to proceed with `value_counts()`, but in the second one I get `DataFrameGroupBy`, I'm trying understand why. Maybe some one can explain me this stuff please.

Comment: Do you mean `df_cat.groupby(['cardio', 'variable'])['value'].size()`?

Answer (score 1):

If interpretted correctly, you're trying to figure out how many times a given combination occurs. In that case you'll also want to incorporate value in your groupby function.

```
data = {'cardio': [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],
       'variable': ['cholesterol', 'cholesterol', 'cholesterol', 'cholesterol', 'cholesterol',
                    'overweight', 'overweight', 'overweight', 'overweight', 'overweight'],
       'value': [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Following function calculates the times a given combination occurs.

```
df.groupby(['cardio', 'variable', 'value'], as_index=False).agg(total=pd.NamedAgg(column = 'value', aggfunc='count'))
```

[image]

Comment: very nice of you to create a [mcve] for OP. I think pd.NamedAgg is redundant here as it's accessed by default when using agg. `.agg(total=('value','count')` would suffice

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I've already found a solution. Now I'm trying to understand theory behind it.
Why does df.groupby('column_1', as_index=True)['column_2'] return SeriesGroupBy while df.groupby('column_1', as_index=False)['column_2'] returns DataFrameGroupBy?

Comment: When `as_index=True` the columns you specify to grouped will be used as index, if you specify just one column, the index will have 1 level. If you specify more, the index will be a multi level index. If `as_index=False`, it'll insert the groupby columns as result columns. Now as you only specify one column in the agg function, the output will only be one column so a pd.Series. If you would specify more columns in the agg function, the result will be more columns so a pd.DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because for *some* operations `DataFrameGroupBy` and `SeriesGroupBy` objects aren't the same.

For the vast majority of arithmetic operations (i.e. sum) there is a method for both the Series ([`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas.Series.sum)) and DataFrame ([`DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)). Since these methods exist for both objects they are then implemented for both the DataFrameGroupBy and SeriesGroupBy object.

However, `value_counts` is an oddity, there is **only** a `Series.value_counts` method; there is no DataFrame equivalent. Because of this you cannot use `.value_counts` with a DataFrameGroupBy object.

---

The other difference is that `Series.GroupBy` and `Dataframe.GroupBy` objects are inherently different. We can see this by interacting with the objects in a small example below. You will see that the `Series.GroupBy` object passes a Series, while the `DataFrameGroupBy` is working with a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
# Sample Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'cardio': list('aaabbb'),
                   'variable': [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

# This makes a Series.GroupBy object.
for keys, gp in df.groupby(['cardio','variable'])['value']:
    print(keys)
    display(gp)

#('a', 0)                     <- Keys are tuples
#0    1                       |
#1    2                       | This is a Series object
#2    3                       |
#Name: value, dtype: int64    |
#
#('b', 0)
#3    4
#4    5
#5    6
#Name: value, dtype: int64

# This creates a DataFrame.GroupBy object
for keys, gp in df.groupby(['cardio','variable'], as_index=False)['value']:
    print(keys)
    display(gp)

#('a', 0)                   <- Keys still same tuple
#  cardio  variable  value  |
#0      a         0      1  | Object is now clearly 
#1      a         0      2  |      a DataFrame
#2      a         0      3  |

#('b', 0)
#  cardio  variable  value
#3      b         0      4
#4      b         0      5
#5      b         0      6
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification! Now I'm trying to understand why `df_cat = df_cat.groupby(['cardio','variable'])['value']` return SeriesGroupBy
while
`df_cat = df_cat.groupby(['cardio','variable'],as_index=False)['value']` return DataFrameGroupBy

Comment: @VasilyPerfilyev the docs are pretty opaque on this fact as who knows what a 'SQL-style' grouped object is, but `as_index=False` essentially passes the entire original DataFrame subset to the rows for each group. So it will be a DataFrame and the ['value']` part is doing nothing to alter the object

Comment: @ALoIIz where are 'cardio', 'variable' and 'value' in seriesGroupBy object (is it object or data structure? or what?) if they are not in keys part and not in object. This means that they are index?

Comment: @VasilyPerfilyev no they're not really anything in the Object. They're just labels for the group. This is why it's so difficult/impossible to access the columns that are the grouping keys for aggregations. In the end they're just used to create the index of the output of the groupby aggregation (if the manipulation reduces to a scalar per group (i.e. sum)).

Comment: @ALoIIz so in case of Series all this 'value, 'cardio', 'variable' are labeling-indexing part (which is neither in object nor in keys) and when as_index=false they go to object part making DataFrame?

Comment: Almost, when you normally group the columns you group on are essentially gone, they're just used to determine the groups, but then are no longer part of your DataFrame/Series (depending what you select after the groupby). When you use `as_index=False` you take a slice of the original DataFrame (all columns) just subset to the rows for that group.

Comment: @ALoIIZ Now it is mostly clear. Thank you very much!